# How can I add spacing each time I insert text into a textbox in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, text, spacing

I have been fiddling with adding spacing between text each time I call an insert to the text box. What I noticed is that when I call it multiple times the spacing is already added but when I have 2 or more lines of .insert all being called at once when I click a button the text is all mushed together with no spacing in between. Attached below are the pictures of the issue and here is my code.

```
taskList.insert("1.end", siteTaskID)
taskList.insert("1.end",siteTaskTXT)
```

siteTaskID and siteTaskTXT are 2 variables holding strings in each. The strings are being decided based off of user input. For instance these variable could be

```
siteTaskID = "HELLO"
siteTaskTXT = "Store"
```

This is really all the necessary code i have written to execute this. I left out the string conversion and also left out the button which calls this function.

[This is when I call both with the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXW8G.png)

[This is when I remove the second .insert function and click the button multiple times (this is what I want to happen when I call both at the same time.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIjqY.png)

Comment: `siteTaskID` are these are just varibales that hold a string? and for me, using `'1.end'` throws an error `bad entry index "1.end"`

Comment: What do you mean 'spacing'? Do you want to do this `tb.insert('1.end', ' ')`? (@CoolCloud The author probably is using tkinter.Text, and you are probably using tkinter.Entry.)

Comment: @oh okay, thanks for specifying, i am dumb

Comment: okay i dont if this will help but try saying, `taskList.insert("1.end", siteTaskID.ljust(6)
taskList.insert("1.end",siteTaskTXT.ljust(6))`

Comment: Your posted code does not have any stuff related to *"adding spacing between text"*.  Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @acw1668 i have added some more information for my code. It is a lot of code so i only added necessary parts.

Comment: Your added information still cannot reproduce the issue and I don't see any code that can produce the result of the second linked image.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The `insert` method will only ever insert exactly what you tell it to. If extra spaces are being inserted, it's because you are passing extra spaces to the insert method.

Comment: @BryanOakley That is what i want. i want extra whitespaces to be passed after each argument but it only does it every time i call it, it doesnt do it when i click it once.

Comment: We need to see code that reproduces the problem. Again, the `insert` method will only insert exactly what you tell it to. If you want extra space, you need to tell it to insert extra space.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `fstring` and put as many spaces as you want between the 2 parts.

```
taskList.insert("1.end", f'{siteTaskID} {siteTaskTXT}')
```

**edit:**
You refuse to post an MRE for some reason so, perceive this shot-in-the-dark

```
from tkinter import Tk, Text, Button 


class App(Tk):
    WIDTH  = 800
    HEIGHT = 600

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.textbox = Text(self)
        self.textbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')

        self.index = 0
        
        #this is the current line you want to affect
        self.cline = 1
        
        #this represents 5 different times you have gathered line data into a list
        #...via a much more dynamic method
        self.vals = [
            ["id1", "text1", "usertext1"],
            ["id2", "text2", "usertext2"],
            ["id3", "text3", "usertext3"],
            ["id4", "text4", "usertext4"],
            ["id5", "text5", "usertext5"],
        ]
        
        #current line data
        self.data = self.vals[self.index]
        
        Button(self, text="click", command=lambda: self.process(self.data)).grid(row=1, column=0)

    #this represents processing a line of gathered data   
    def process(self, data):
        if data: 
            self.textbox.insert(f'{self.cline}.end', f'{" ".join(data)}\n')
        
        #below is only necessary for this example
        #the equivalents should be done somewhere else
        self.cline += 1
        self.index += 1
        self.data = self.vals[self.index] if self.index < len(self.vals) else None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.title("My Application")
    app.geometry(f'{App.WIDTH}x{App.HEIGHT}')
    app.mainloop()
```

**aside**

Judging from your comment it would seem you are trying to cheat a quality method, like a table full of `Label` or `Entry`, for a inferior method of space formatting a `Text` widget into a table-like display. If that is the case, you may want to consider that your current method is a complete waste of time and will give you more headaches than results.

Comment: This would work but these 2 are just the start of adding more variables across the page. Also most of them are user typed in so the length will be changing.

Comment: @omen ~ that means your example is not a minimal reproducible one. `1.end` means "the end of line 1". Spaces are never going to just appear. You will always have to pad the input manually. The reason you got spaces when you tried your second way is probably because you have some error that allowed sideTaskID to be nothing but a space. Post an example that includes all of your conditions or see my edit and accept it.